# Passing argument within action selection in UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Given that you have a method

```
-(void)aSelector:(id)anyArgument;
```

And have set up a UIButton programmatically

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init]
```

Alright, I get the idea that when you create a UIButton, you have to use the method

```
[myButton addTarget:nil action@selector(aSelector:) for ControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But where do I pass the argument?  I know that normally, you would use

```
[myButton withObject:anyArgument];
```

But NSControl doesn't allow for that but it is possible as the colon after the selector name indicates so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, -aSelector: will be defined like this

```
- (void) aSelector:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@" sender = %@", sender);
}
```

and the argument will be myButton. Bear in mind that you might have several buttons all calling the method -aSelector: and you would, then, need to distinguish which was the caller (sender) at runtime.

Comment: Correct.  And just to clarify: The argument passed is the control that triggered the action.  In this case, `myButton`.

Comment: Note also that you can set a "tag" property on individual controls, so if you have more than one control hooked up to the same action, you can determine which is which by examining the tag.

Answer (score 2):

addTarget of UIControl only supports these three forms of selectors.

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

you can't add custom arguments.