# Adding arguments to selector in addTarget

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arguments, selector

I'm having trouble adding arguments to the selector of a button (programmatically created). I've looked around the internet and tried some things, but I can't figure it out.

I create a button with the following line:

```
NSString *someThing = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"someThing"];
int counter = 4;
[anotherButton addTarget:self action:@selector(alertPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I've got the function `alertPressed`:

```
-(void)alertPressed:(id)sender {

}
```

How can I transfer those two variables to `alertPressed`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992812/passing-argument-within-action-selection-in-uibutton

Comment: @Till: the only thing I'm getting out of that thread, is that it isn't possible because I can use three forms of selectors only? I just want to pass on a variable to that method...

Comment: I know what you intend to and the link I provided clearly explains to you that this was not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `UIButton`, with a custom button that contains those attributes. Then, your `(id)sender` can be cast to your custom button and you can obtain the set values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not global variables or properties in your class?

Comment: Because I have multiple buttons linked to the same function, so it depends on what button is pressed. Those buttons are created in a loop: they can be with 10000ths of them, for example. The class is big enough as is, I could be using a property, again, but it should be easily transferable, no?

Comment: In that case I would use "tag" property of UIButton as stated in the link above, and set variables depending on button in alertPressed. I don't think you can transfer those variables in other way ...